# Nginx rewrite rules for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, nginx, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

Earlier my web server worked on Apache, now only at Nginx.

I tried rewrite all rules for this example: 
http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/

But still all URL same as:
mysite.com/stocks
dont work.
Where **stocks** - is name of controller Codeigniter.

In **.htaccess** file were the next rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And **config.php** had the following content:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol']    = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Front_Controller_Pattern_based_packages

Comment: Thanks, wanna share one russian service for convert htaccess to nginx config: http://winginx.com/ru/htaccess